# How much actual alcohol is safe to drink per day?

Tags: drinking

Ok, so I'm 17 and only recently started drinking.
I'm experimenting and learning, I'm looking to drink for nothing but pleasure, no exaggerations or excesses.

So, you look at a label and you see x% alcohol, which means, well what it means.

And what I intend to know is how much actual "pure" alcohol would be safe to drink on a daily basis, so I can do the math and find out how much of each drink I can drink in a day and stay as healthy as I've ever been.

(I'm ~1.6m tall, and weigh ~57Kg)

Thank you.

Comment: Totally depends on the individual. Everyone I knew at university drank to massive excess - most are fine now, some aren't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CDC suggests no more than 2 drinks a day as moderate drinking.

The National Institute on Alcohol Abuse and Alcoholism suggests no more than 4 drinks per day, and no more than 7 drinks per week, to stay at a low risk for an alcohol use.

At 17 your brain is still developing and imbibing alcohol runs the very real risk of affecting that development. Drink in moderation.

In response to the below comment, a single drink technically does vary but about 45ml / 1.5oz of spirit (e.g. vodka), a 5oz glass of wine, or a 12oz beer.

When I say it varies, different locations have different measurements. Check out this page:

[Standard drink (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_drink)

Comment: How much is a "drink"?